# if then else vs the ternary operator ( ? :) in c#

Tags: c#

`this.value1` and `c.value1` can both be either null or non-null. So a total of 4 combinations to test. `value2` can also be null or non-null.

Can the if-then-else's below be replaced by something shorter like use the ternary operator ( if then else using the `? :` operators) - and would that be a bad practice for this specific case because we are testing 4 combinations for `value1` and `value2`?

```
     public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {
        bool value1_check = false;
        bool value2_check = false;
        var c = obj as ObjectType;

        if (this.value1 != null)
               value1_check = this.value1.Equals(c.value1);
        else if ((this.value1 == null) && (c.value1 == null))
               value1_check = true;
        else if ((this.value1 == null) && (c.value1 != null))
              value1_check = c.value1.Equals(this.value1);

        if (this.value2 != null)
               value2_check = this.value2.Equals(c.value2);
        else if ((this.value2 == null) && (c.value2 == null))
               value2_check = true;
        else if ((this.value2 == null) && (c.value2 != null))
              value2_check = c.value2.Equals(this.value2);

        return (value1_check && value2_check);
     }
```

Comment: I hope you're also overriding `GetHashCode()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `Object.Equals()`, which already does all that.

```
return Equals(this.Value1, c.Value1)
    && Equals(this.Value2, c.Value2);
```

Comment: I think you'd need to check `c` for `null` first.

Comment: SLaks - do you mean that this.Equals(this.Value1, c.Value1) is the same as if (this.value1 != null)
               value1_check = this.value1.Equals(c.value1);
        else if ((this.value1 == null) && (c.value1 == null))
               value1_check = true;
        else if ((this.value1 == null) && (c.value1 != null))
              value1_check = c.value1.Equals(this.value1);

Comment: @user1216456: Not `this.Equals(a,b)`, but the static version of `Equals`, i.e. `object.Equals(a,b)`. SLaks didn't put anything before `Equals` because it's not strinclty required, but imagine the posted code as `return object.Equals(this.Value1, ...`

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you might want the [?? Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

```
var lhs= this.value1 ?? c.value1 ?? null;
var rhs = c.value1 ?? this.value1 ?? null;
var value1Check = lhs == rhs
```

Should do the same thing as yours, but almost 100% less readable!

Comment: I have to give this a +1 for being just so horrible!

Answer (score 0):

If your still wondering about the ternary option.

```
 value1_check= this.value1!=null? this.value1.Equals(c.value1):(c.value1!=null?c.value.Equals(this.value):value1_check=true);
```